# How to call a function in an preg_replace?

Tags: php, preg-replace

How can I call a function within `preg_replace()`?

```
$template = '<div> [BILD="123"][BILD="246"] </div>'; 

$pat = '/\[BILD="(.*?)"\]\[BILD ="(.*?)"\]/';
$ret = getImageArea($id, $config, '$1', '$2'); 
return preg_replace($pat, $rep, $template);
```

It fails opening the function and doesn't sends 123 or 246.
It just sends $1 and $2.

Comment: Of course it sends `$1` and `$2`, that's what you wrote. Look into `preg_replace_callback`.

Comment: You called `getImageArea` before you even called `preg_replace`. Even if the variables did what you expected (I'm guessing you're used to Perl), how would it work in that order?

Comment: Where exactly are you telling it to call a function? The only way to call a function used to be the deprecated 'e' flag and I cannot see anywhere.

Comment: If I don't use a function and just make $ret = '$1 $2'; it says <div> 123 246 </dvi>. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: And how do I solve this with 'e'? Or how do I solve this with calling the function afterwards? How would preg_replace_callback work with an array of $pat and $ret?

Comment: `$1` and `$2` only have special meaning inside the replacement string of `preg_replace`. They don't have any special meaning when you use them in the arguments to other functions.

Comment: Use `preg_replace_callback` instead. The way you've done it, you call `getImageArea` _before_ replace is done.

Comment: You don't use the `e` flag: it's **deprecated**. You have to use `preg_replace_callback()` but you need to read the docs, you can't just try to guess what the arguments should look like.

Comment: I don't find any useful preg_replace_callback() tutorial :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I (and many others) told in comments, you have to use [**preg_replace_callback**](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback) in this case. One possible approach:

```
$template = '<div> [BILD="123"][BILD="246"] </div>';
$pat = '/\[BILD="(.*?)"\]\[BILD="(.*?)"\]/';

return preg_replace_callback($pat, function($matches) use($id, $config) {
  return getImageArea($id, $config, $matches[1], $matches[2]);
}, $template);
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/93029). As you see, it's quite straight-forward; the only catch is making `$id` and `$config` variables available inside the callback (which is done with `use` op).

Comment: AWESOME!!! Thanks for your help. Didn't find anything like this on the web. You're my hero haha :)

Comment: @zerophreak - You seem to be avoiding the official manual as Hell. Googling for random tutorials is never going to be as good.